# After deleting my database I'm still getting "ProgrammingError: column post_post.hash does not exist"

Tags: python, django

How is this possible? I did `python manage.py flush` which deleted the database. I also uninstalled and re-installed django. I then did `makemigrations` and `migrate`. But I'm getting this error in my `log.django` file:

```
  File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column post_post.hash does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "post_post"."id", "post_post"."hash", "post_post"."us...
```

It's referring to my models here:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=18, default=random_string, null=True, blank=True)


class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: flush deletes only the data, not the database. If you like to delete the database, you have to do it by hand `DROP DATABASE databasename` and rerun `migrate`

Comment: yep this fixes it - thanks!

Comment: glad I could help, I think I should've made an answer insted of a comment (sorry, pretty new here ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flush` deletes only the data, not the database. 
If you like to delete the database, you have to do it by hand, e.g. with SQL: `DROP DATABASE databasename` and rerun `migrate`.